# Anyway to open file explorer and return location of selected file

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way which allows the user to open the file explorer once a button has been pressed, and allow the user to choose an image file, but instead of opening it, return the file location. Is there anyway this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

The question depends, what API are you intending to use?

Swing has [`JFileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

AWT has [`FileDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FileDialog.html)

JavaFX has [`FileChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm)

For example...

Comment: I'm intending to use JavaFX

Comment: Take a look at the supplied link. It should just about provide you with everything you need...